# Moderation & curation strike: Mistrust, mistreat, and harmful imposed policies

Tags: discussion, moderation, community

[Main post on Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389811/383809) with some history, details, explanations, and calls to action.

Here, in short:

As of June 5, 2023, I am on [**the general moderation and curation strike**](https://openletter.mousetail.nl/). As a moderator of Computational Science SE, I protest the breakdown of communication and trust between the corporate (Stack Overflow Inc.) and its communities. Particularly, the last straw was the sudden introduction of the new [AI-generated content moderation policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389582/383809), which (together with **not** yet publicly **announced guidance** given to moderators), effectively makes reasonable moderation of such content impossible.

This is against the wishes of many SE communities, as well as my understanding of the quality content curation that makes Stack Exchange a valuable resource. See also [Stack Exchange is failing its community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389558/383809) and [What has happened to lead moderators to consider striking?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424979/2452869) for more details.

Has AI-generated content problem already been a major issue for Computational Science SE? Not yet, as far as I know. However, many other sites have been, and its non-automated curation was essential. So, for Computational Science SE it is just a matter of time.

In conclusion:

**A general moderation strike is being held until the concerns laid out in the open letter are addressed. Moderators, curators, contributors, and users, you are welcome to join in by signing your name in the [strike letter](https://openletter.mousetail.nl/).**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [Result of negotiations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390106/383809), I believe that the main immediate concerns have been addressed; hence, I am no longer on strike. I also believe that most strike participants are no longer on strike as well.

While I am quite happy that the agreement has been reached, I am still very concerned about the fact that the community and moderators had to declare a strike to achieve something as well as the general behaviour of the "corporates" before and during the strike. I am also very closely watching the development of the policies and various mechanics at SE that can easily destroy many Stack Exchange communities individually (including Computational Science), as well as the Stack Exchange as a whole (from the community point of view, of course).